# Why is the attribute empty in this case?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have a jokes object in a class and the attribute of that is set in the getJokes action. If I dump it, I see the expected data, however when I need the data in showJokes action the object is empty. Why?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Services\JokeApiService;
use App\Store\JokeStore;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class JokeController extends Controller
{
    private $_jokeApiService;
    private $_jokes;

    public function __construct(JokeApiService $jokeApiService, JokeStore $jokes)
    {
        $this->_jokeApiService = $jokeApiService;
        $this->_jokes = $jokes;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view("index");
    }

    public function showJokes()
    {

        //The object null here
        dd($this->_jokes->getJokes());

        return view("showJokes")->with("jokes", $this->_jokes->getJokes());
    }

    public function getJokes(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'number_of_jokes' => 'required|integer|between:1,20',
        ]);

        $result = $this->_jokeApiService->LoadJokes();

        $this->_jokes->setJokes($result);

        //The object has tha data expected
        //dd($this->_jokes->getJokes());

        return redirect()->action("JokeController@showJokes");
    }
}
```

Comment: because you have set  jokes in `getJokes` action. however, showJokes didn't. They are from different instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing that to avoid calling your database multiple times.
(but it's not a good idea if what i'm supposing is true, think about having 1 million jokes, do you want to load it all in your jokes attribute?  ).

In the process `request -> response`, you have different instances of JokeController.

That means even if you request the getJokes action, you will fill the jokes attribute. but until you get the response, the instance of JokeController is destructed. so when you call again the showJokes . another instance is available here. so the jokes are empty.

To solve this issue, there is a lot of manners like :

sending the id which identifies the joke in your DBMS to get it by repository and then return it.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot use database, I would like to load jokes from 3 different API (10 from each) combine them into one and display it to the user who can set the number of jokes(max 20). That's why I came up with a "store" idea.

Comment: does this api have for exmaple an endpoint which can return detail of a given joke id ?

Comment: yes, https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/endpoints my other idea would be storing it in the session

Comment: I don't think so. since if your server is shut down, your session is destructed. 
what about storing it in a database (in case of those endpoints change fastly, think about creating a command which can update the data in the database).  Maybe using a Redis server for storing also.